# MySQL + PHP: Avoid duplicate result due to two results from joined table

Tags: php, mysql

I've been struggling with the following case:

**FIRST APPROACH:**

```
SELECT * FROM vinyl_tracks vt
INNER JOIN vinyl_keys vk ON vt.mKeyID = vk.mKeyID
INNER JOIN vinyl_tracks_styles vts ON vt.trackID = vts.trackID
INNER JOIN vinyl_styles vs ON vts.styleID = vs.styleID
WHERE vinylID = :vinylID
```

For some of the tracks, table `vts` will contain two or more styles (the table only contains the `trackID` and `styleID` on separate rows. This causes the entire result to repeat. I've tried `DISTINCT`, and all sorts of `GROUP BY`, including both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`. This does return one result per track but the second `styleID` is missing.

Here is the `var_dump` of this query without any `GROUP BY`:

```
array (size=4)
0 => 
  array (size=10)
    'trackID' => string '868' (length=3)
    'vinylID' => string '249' (length=3)
    'side' => string 'A' (length=1)
    'trackArtist' => string '' (length=0)
    'trackTitle' => string 'Waiting (John Creamer & Stephane K Remix)' (length=41)
    'notes' => string '130 bpm' (length=7)
    'mKeyID' => string '1' (length=1)
    'mKey' => string 'A major' (length=7)
    'Camelot' => string '11B' (length=3)
    'styleID' => string '8' (length=1)
1 => 
  array (size=10)
    'trackID' => string '868' (length=3)
    'vinylID' => string '249' (length=3)
    'side' => string 'A' (length=1)
    'trackArtist' => string '' (length=0)
    'trackTitle' => string 'Waiting (John Creamer & Stephane K Remix)' (length=41)
    'notes' => string '130 bpm' (length=7)
    'mKeyID' => string '1' (length=1)
    'mKey' => string 'A major' (length=7)
    'Camelot' => string '11B' (length=3)
    'styleID' => string '17' (length=2)
2 => 
  array (size=10)
    'trackID' => string '869' (length=3)
    'vinylID' => string '249' (length=3)
    'side' => string 'B' (length=1)
    'trackArtist' => string '' (length=0)
    'trackTitle' => string 'Waiting (Jay Welsh (Black Ice) Remix)' (length=37)
    'notes' => string '135 bpm' (length=7)
    'mKeyID' => string '1' (length=1)
    'mKey' => string 'A major' (length=7)
    'Camelot' => string '11B' (length=3)
    'styleID' => string '17' (length=2)
3 => 
  array (size=10)
    'trackID' => string '869' (length=3)
    'vinylID' => string '249' (length=3)
    'side' => string 'B' (length=1)
    'trackArtist' => string '' (length=0)
    'trackTitle' => string 'Waiting (Jay Welsh (Black Ice) Remix)' (length=37)
    'notes' => string '135 bpm' (length=7)
    'mKeyID' => string '1' (length=1)
    'mKey' => string 'A major' (length=7)
    'Camelot' => string '11B' (length=3)
    'styleID' => string '8' (length=1)
```

Then I run another query to fetch all styles so I can populate the multiple select drop down. This is what it looks like with the `foreach` loop to create the dropdown and a screenshot – the two tracks, each having two styles, are shown as four tracks:

```
$allStylesQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM vinyl_styles ORDER BY styleID ASC");
$allStylesQuery->execute();
$styles = $allStylesQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stylesSelector = "<select multiple=\"multiple\" class=\"form-control form-control-sm stylesSelector\" name=\"styleID[".$trow['trackID']."][]\"><option> &ndash; </option>";
foreach($styles as $style) {
    if(isset($trow['styleID']) && ($trow['styleID'] == $style['styleID'])) {
        $stylesSelector .= "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
    }
    else {
        $stylesSelector .= "<option value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
    }
}
$stylesSelector .= "</select>";
```

[image: Results from first approach – two tracks shown as four]

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH:**
I've also tried to accomplish the same using two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM vinyl_tracks vt
INNER JOIN vinyl_keys vk ON vt.mKeyID = vk.mKeyID
WHERE vinylID = :vinylID
```

Then, inside the `foreach` loop to get the results from the first query, the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM vinyl_tracks_styles vts
RIGHT JOIN vinyl_styles vs ON vts.styleID = vs.styleID
WHERE vts.trackID = :trackID
```

This alternative way produces the results I want, e.g.:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
    'trackID' => string '868' (length=3)
    'styleID' => string '8' (length=1)
    'styleName' => string 'progressive house' (length=17)
 1 => 
   array (size=3)
    'trackID' => string '868' (length=3)
    'styleID' => string '17' (length=2)
    'styleName' => string 'progressive trance' (length=18)
```

But then I fail at displaying the results the I way I need them, which is:
[image: one row per track, all styles shown in a multiple select]

In order to list all possible styles in the select dropdown, I need to run one more query (the `WHERE` condition above prevents all style names and IDs from displaying despite the `RIGHT JOIN`, I know):

```
SELECT * FROM vinyl_styles ORDER BY styleID ASC
```

And the only way to highlight the select options (styles) that I've found is to nest two `foreach` loops inside one another, which of course again leads to duplicate results:

```
$trackStylesQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM vinyl_tracks_styles vts
                        RIGHT JOIN vinyl_styles vs ON vts.styleID = vs.styleID
                        WHERE vts.trackID = :trackID");
$trackStylesQuery->bindParam(':trackID', $trow['trackID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$trackStylesQuery->execute();
$trackStyles = $trackStylesQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//var_dump($trackStyles);

$allStylesQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM vinyl_styles ORDER BY styleID ASC");
$allStylesQuery->execute();
$styles = $allStylesQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stylesSelector = "<select multiple=\"multiple\" class=\"form-control form-control-sm stylesSelector\" name=\"styleID[".$trow['trackID']."][]\"><option> &ndash; </option>";
foreach($styles as $style) {
    foreach($trackStyles as $trackStyle) {
        if(isset($trackStyle['styleID']) && ($trackStyle['styleID'] == $style['styleID'])) {
            $stylesSelector .= "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
        }
        else {
            $stylesSelector .= "<option value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
        }
    }
}
$stylesSelector .= "</select>";
```

[image: Styles repeated twice in select dropdown, the second style is highlighted too]

If I stick to the first one-query variant above, the entire row of inputs is repeated twice, so for these two tracks I get four rows.

I'm really out of ideas, please help.

**UPDATE**

Going with the fewer-queries approach suggested by @Ultimater I have now arrived at a situation where I have all the details I need, the only problem being that the styles list is repeated inside the styles dropdown for each style that a track has. If only one style or no styles have been added for a track, there is no problem. Posting my full code below:

```
$tracksQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT vt.trackID, vt.vinylID, vt.side, vt.trackArtist, vt.trackTitle, vt.notes, vt.mKeyID, vk.mKey, vk.Camelot, 
                            GROUP_CONCAT(vts.styleID SEPARATOR ',') AS 'styleIDs',
                            GROUP_CONCAT(vs.styleName SEPARATOR ',') AS 'styleNames'
                            FROM vinyl_tracks vt
                            INNER JOIN vinyl_keys vk ON vt.mKeyID = vk.mKeyID
                            LEFT JOIN vinyl_tracks_styles vts ON vt.trackID = vts.trackID
                            LEFT JOIN vinyl_styles vs ON vts.styleID = vs.styleID
                            WHERE vt.vinylID = :vinylID
                            GROUP BY vt.trackID");
$tracksQuery->bindParam(':vinylID', $vinylID);
$tracksQuery->execute();
$tracks = $tracksQuery->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//var_dump($tracks);

// fetch all styles to use in the dropdown
$allStylesQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM vinyl_styles ORDER BY styleID ASC");
$allStylesQuery->execute();
$styles = $allStylesQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// build a dropdown menu for each of the tracks
// which contains all styles and where the current track's styles are selected
$stylesSelector = "";

foreach($tracks as $track) {

    // start building the selector
    $stylesSelector .= "<select multiple=\"multiple\" class=\"form-control form-control-sm\" name=\"styleID[".$track['trackID']."][]\"><option> &ndash; </option>";

            // check if any styles have been added for this track
    if(!empty($track['styleIDs'])) {

        // check if StyleIDs and StyleNames results contain a comma
        // which means more than one style has been added for that track
        if((strpos($track['styleIDs'], ',')) && (strpos($track['styleNames'], ','))) {

            // separate trackStyleIDs and trackStyleNames
            $trackStyleIDs = explode(',', $track['styleIDs']);
            $trackStyleNames = explode(',', $track['styleNames']);

            // now combine them in one array where styleID is the key and styleName is the value
            $styleIDs_and_Names = array_combine($trackStyleIDs, $trackStyleNames);

            // for each of the styleID => styleName pairs in the array
            // check against all available styles if selected
            foreach($styleIDs_and_Names as $styleID => $styleName) {

                // iterate over all available styles
                foreach($styles as $style) {

                    // if there's a match, add "selected" to the option
                    if($styleID == $style['styleID']) {
                        $stylesSelector .= "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
                    }
                    else {
                        $stylesSelector .= "<option value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // only one style has been added for this track
        else {
            // iterate over all available styles
            foreach($styles as $style) {

                // if there's a match, add "selected" to the option
                if($track['styleIDs'] == $style['styleID']) {
                    $stylesSelector .= "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
                }
                else {
                    $stylesSelector .= "<option value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // if no styles have been added for this track
    else {
        // iterate all available styles
        foreach($styles as $style) {
            $stylesSelector .= "<option value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
        }
    }
    $stylesSelector .= "</select>";
}
```

The following screenshot shows the actual page section generated by the above code. Must be something obvious and easy for experts that I'm missing but I still can't see it.
[image: styles repeated inside selector for each style]

Comment: This doesn't help, I'm afraid. It causes the second track to be completely omitted from the query result, while the first track (having two styles) is still shown as two separate nested arrays.

Comment: your question si not clear  .. try add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ...  the use select *   ..in your code don't help

Comment: I see now. You have to seperate your queries more. 1) write a query to fetch albums (without worrying about styles) 2) write a query to fetch all the styles per album and store them in array like `$types[$album_id][] = $style` 3) write a query to fetch all the style to display in the dropdown

Comment: I think the issue is your working solution uses an INNER JOIN as well as a RIGHT JOIN. But you're trying to simulate this with only INNER JOINs in your triple join. You'd need to change one of your INNER JOINs to either a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN. Currently not sure off the top of my head how to make these adjustments to your triple join...

Comment: @Ultimater Nothing changes even if I change the `RIGHT JOIN` to `INNER` in the sub-query to retrieve the styles for each track. Just tried changing the two `INNER JOIN` in the first query to `RIGHT` – nothing changes, I still get one array containing four sub-arrays, that is, the data is still duplicate.

Comment: Ofc the data is "duplicate" as you have more styles per album...

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, and this is what I can't sort out. I'm not sure I fully understand what you propose above, I'll try some more to comprehend it. But I thought this is what I do (more or less) in the alternative variant: 1) query to fetch the tracks and their details, 2) query to fetch the styles per track, 3) query to fetch all styles.

Comment: Your data results show different combinations of track and style ids. It isn't actually duplicate data. The thing is you need an array within an array to represent your results nicely. Namely you have an array of tracks, then you need a subarray containing the styles for that album.  Your results are correct represented in 2D, and you'd need to loop them in PHP to display it nicely. Alternatively, you could find a different way you want MySQL to represent your results as 2D data. You could for example `GROUP_CONCAT()` your styles to give you the ability to express your 3D data as 2D data.

Comment: @Ultimater And this is where I get lost. Please provide the code you suggest. (Also see the details I've added to my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get your results down to two dimensions so you don't get duplicate albums merely to populate a styles dropdown.
Instead you'd group concat the styles and make it pretty using the new line character.

Your query would wind up looking something like this:

```
SELECT
  trackID,
  vinylID,
  side,
  trackArtist,
  trackTitle,
  notes,
  GROUP_CONCAT(mKeyID SEPARATOR '\n') as 'mKeyIDs',
  GROUP_CONCAT(mKey SEPARATOR '\n') as 'mKeys',
  Camelot,
  GROUP_CONCAT(styleID SEPARATOR '\n') AS 'styleIDs',
  GROUP_CONCAT(styleName SEPARATOR '\n') AS 'styleNames'
FROM
  vinyl_tracks vt
INNER JOIN
  vinyl_keys vk ON vt.mKeyID = vk.mKeyID
INNER JOIN
  vinyl_tracks_styles vts ON vt.trackID = vts.trackID
INNER JOIN
  vinyl_styles vs ON vts.styleID = vs.styleID
GROUP BY
  vt.trackID
WHERE
  vinylID = :vinylID
```

I am grouping here by track id because that appears to be the criteria you are using to determine whether something is a duplicate or not. From there, I'm using GROUP_CONCAT with the new line separator to show all your styles affected by this group by in the same cell. Your PHP could refer to this cell, and explode on the new line character to get what it needs for populating the dropdown.

Make sure this query works directly on the database first to see if you need to make adjustments to it.

### JSON approach:

Alternatively, if your MySQL version supports [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg), you could use it instead of GROUP_CONCAT to accomplish the functionally equivalent behavior albeit the much cleaner:

```
SELECT
  trackID,
  vinylID,
  side,
  trackArtist,
  trackTitle,
  notes,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(mKeyID) AS 'mKeyIDs',
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(mKey) AS 'mKeys',
  Camelot,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(styleID) AS 'styleIDs',
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(styleName) AS 'styleNames'
FROM
  vinyl_tracks vt
INNER JOIN
  vinyl_keys vk ON vt.mKeyID = vk.mKeyID
INNER JOIN
  vinyl_tracks_styles vts ON vt.trackID = vts.trackID
INNER JOIN
  vinyl_styles vs ON vts.styleID = vs.styleID
GROUP BY
  vt.trackID
WHERE
  vinylID = :vinylID
```

Then in your PHP you'd simply reference `$row['styleIDs']` and `$row['styleNames']` to generate the key=>value pair for each option used in your "Styles" dropdown.

For the musical "Keys" dropdown options, you'd reference `$row['mKeyID']` and `$row['mKeys']`  to generate the key=>value pair for each option used in your "Keys" dropdown.

**Update:**

I set this up locally and see the problem the OP is running into. My query is fine. However when trying to display the dropdown, OP is running into a bug with his or her PHP looping logic. More specifically the following logic is faulty:

```
        foreach($styles as $style) {

            // if there's a match, add "selected" to the option
            if($track['styleIDs'] == $style['styleID']) {
                $stylesSelector .= "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
            }
            else {
                $stylesSelector .= "<option value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Now that I understand what the OP is trying to do, let's just rewrite the entire mess. I have refactored the code. I have also tested this locally:

```
$tracksQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT vt.trackID, vt.vinylID, vt.side, vt.trackArtist, vt.trackTitle, vt.notes, vt.mKeyID, vk.mKey, vk.Camelot, 
                            GROUP_CONCAT(vts.styleID SEPARATOR ',') AS 'styleIDs'
                            FROM vinyl_tracks vt
                            INNER JOIN vinyl_keys vk ON vt.mKeyID = vk.mKeyID
                            LEFT JOIN vinyl_tracks_styles vts ON vt.trackID = vts.trackID
                            WHERE vt.vinylID = :vinylID
                            GROUP BY vt.trackID");
$tracksQuery->bindParam(':vinylID', $vinylID);
$tracksQuery->execute();
$tracks = $tracksQuery->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$allStylesQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM vinyl_styles ORDER BY styleID ASC");
$allStylesQuery->execute();
$styles = $allStylesQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$stylesSelector = "";

foreach($tracks as $track)
{

    $stylesSelector .= "<select multiple=\"multiple\" class=\"form-control form-control-sm\" name=\"styleID[".$track['trackID']."][]\"><option> &ndash; </option>";
    $trackStyleIDs = explode(',', $track['styleIDs']);
    foreach($styles as $style)
    {
        $optionValue = $style['styleID'];
        $optionText = $style['styleName'];
        $optionSelected = in_array($optionValue, $trackStyleIDs) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
        $stylesSelector .= sprintf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $optionValue,$optionSelected,$optionText);
    }

    $stylesSelector .= "</select>";
}
```

Comment: This query (the `GROUP_CONCAT` approach) does fetch the results I need, thanks! But I'm stuck generating the select dropdown. I don't quite understand what the "simply reference `$track['styleIDs']` and `$track['styleNames']` (I use `track` instead of `row`)" involves.    I changed the separator in the query to a comma, then – as I loop through all the possible styles in the dropdown – `explode` this to make an array, then loop that in a `foreach($trackStyles as $trackStyle)`, but I have two problems: 1) only the styles for the specific track are displayed and 2) I can't get the style names.

Comment: Perhaps I need to create a new array by merging the styleIDs and styleNames arrays first? I'll try this now.

Comment: @cheeseus You'd combine and loop it like so: `foreach(array_combine(json_decode($row['styleIDs']),json_decode($row['styleNames'])) as $id=>$name){ ... }`

Comment: Yes, this is what I did: `$styleIDs_and_Names = array_combine($trackStyleIDs, $trackStyleNames);` , then `foreach($styleIDs_and_Names as $styleID => $styleName) { if($styleID == $style['styleID']) { $stylesSelector .= "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$styleName."</option>"; }` But when I add `else` to this to display the rest of the styles, again all styles are listed twice in the dropdown... I don't understand what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: @cheeseus Ah, I think you also have to do the same for the musical `Keys` dropdown. Same approach with either the GROUP_CONCAT or JSON_ARRAYAGG then you'd need to reference mKeyID and mKey to create a similar key=>value list you can loop. I have updated my answer so you have the keys dropdown too.

Comment: The musical keys display just fine :) But I can't get the styles dropdown to not repeat the styles. The closest I get to what I need is by putting the non-selected options outside the `foreach` loop – this way only the selected options are repeated: `foreach($styleIDs_and_Names as $styleID => $styleName) { if($styleID == $style['styleID']) { $stylesSelector .= "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$styleName."</option>"; } } $stylesSelector .= "<option value=\"".$style['styleID']."\">".$style['styleName']."</option>";`

Comment: @cheeseus You're putting too much nested responsibility in one place. Isolate the responsibilities by abstracting over the problem. I'd create a dropdown builder function. Send it your array list of options as one parameter, and the option to select as another parameter. If it's only an issue with getting the "selected" option to select, then it sounds like my query logic is working nicely. You could even choose the default selected option with JavaScript later if it's any easier and rid yourself of such loops on the backend and leave it to the frontend. Or is it an issue with the query?

Comment: If there's some other issue going on we're not seeing, you could even have such a builder use array_unique to remove duplicates. Then address the issue directly once you find the remaining duplicate cause. If you're using `array_combine` then the data should already be unique. You're just not looping correctly and best to have a dedicated function to take some of this responsibility to make the logic easier.

Comment: Your query works just fine but I don't understand how to remove the duplicate options from the dropdown. Your explanation is beyond me as I'm not nearly as good at PHP/JavaScript as to grasp it.

Comment: @cheeseus please update question and provide var_dump of the the key->value array you're claiming has duplicates. There shouldn't be any duplicates is what I'm saying...

Comment: Maybe my wording is not precise. What I see as "duplicate" is the same track repeated twice because of the two different styles: this creates two arrays that are identical except for one element (the var_dump is in my question). And this results in unwanted repetition. Everything I've tried ends up the same way – either the entire track for each style is repeated, or the styles are shown twice in the same dropdown (using the query from the other answer).

Comment: @cheeseus Have you tried using my latest query that uses four GROUP_CONCAT's instead of two? Each dropdown needs its own GROUP_CONCAT or you'll see data repeated. I'd need to test this with an actual test schema to re-create the issue. Will try to get back to you within the next 14 hours.

Comment: No, I haven't, sorry, been too busy doing other stuff. By "four GROUP_CONCATs" I suppose you mean the `JSON_ARRAYAGG`. I will mark your answer as accepted and will try that approach later – or will just give up. Even if the styles are repeated twice in one dropdown, I will be able to submit selections to the database – and I am only using this on my local server at home for personal needs (to help me manage my vinyl collection).

Comment: @cheeseus I was able to re-create the issue you were describing. I have updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: EUREKA! Thank you for going the extra couple of miles!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192798/discussion-between-cheeseus-and-ultimater).

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you have to breakdown the process in 2 steps.

- First step is simply fetch the basic information of a track.
- Second step is to fetch all the according styles of the track in a separate array

After you've stored the style seperatetly, you would now have an array like this,

```
[
    track_id_1 => [ style_id_1, style_id_2, ]
    track_id_2 => [ style_id_x, style_id_y, ]
]
```

Meaning if you know the track id and the style id you can test whether the style is attached to the current track with `in_array`:

```
<?php
     if (in_array($style_id, $styles_per_track[$track_id])) {
         echo 'Style '.$style_id.' is attached to track '.$track_id;
     }
```

---

A mock up of this solution would be the following.
(*do note I did not test any of this code, it's just to give you an idea to separate the data*)

```
    <?php
        // Step 1: Fetch all tracks w/out worrying about styles
        $tracks_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM vinyl_tracks vt WHERE vinylID=:vinylID');
        $track_stmt->execute([':vinylID' => $vinylID, ]);

        $tracks = $track_stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Step 2: Loop each track and store the styles accordingly
        $styles_per_track = [];
        $styles_per_track_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM vinyl_tracks_styles vts WHERE trackId=:trackId')

        foreach($tracks as $track) {
            $vinyl_tracks_styles[$track['trackID']] = [];
            $styles_per_track_stmt->execute($track['trackID']);
            $temp = $styles_per_track_stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($temp as $style_per_track) $vinyl_tracks_styles[$track['trackID']] = $style_per_track['styleID'];
        }

        //fetch styles
        /**
        ...
        ...
        ...
        **/
        foreach($tracks as $track) {
    ?>
            <select name="track[<?=$track['trackID'];?>" multiple>
    <?php
            foreach($styles as $style) {
    ?>
                <option value="<?= $style['styleID']; ?>" <?php if(in_array($style['styleID'], $styles_per_track[$track['trackID']])) { echo ' selected'; } ?>><?= $style['styleName']; ?></option>
    <?php
            }
    ?>
        </select>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I've tried using the code you've provided (introducing whatever changes are required) but it doesn't seem to work. I get `undefined offset 868` (this is the trackID) for this line: `if(in_array($style['styleID'], $styles_per_track[$track['trackID']])) `

Comment: Ah because that track doesn't have any styles. U would need to change the `if` to `isset($styles_per_track[$track['trackID']]) && in_array($style['styleID'], $styles_per_track[$track['trackID']])`

Comment: Both tracks from this vinyl that I've been playing with have two styles each. Changing the `if` to `isset` doesn't work as that breaks the code completely :(